# AngularJS Timing - How to make child scope see parent's $broadcast on init?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, broadcast, timing

When my app starts up there is a main template controller and a child template controller. The route is looks like this...

```
#/history/?q=someQuery
```

The main template controller does this on init...

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('searchQueryChanged', $location.search().q);
```

The child controller does this...

```
$scope.$on('searchQueryChanged', function(e, sQuery){
  console.log(sQuery);
});
```

I can see by logging that the child controller initializes BEFORE the main template controller. So in theory it *should* respond to the broadcast, but it doesn't. Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: try using a shared service if this is not working.

Comment: use abstract=true as a property in your parent controller route..

Answer (score 2):

You can use $timeout provider to be sure that your $broadcast is the last thing executed in angular's life cycle:

```
$timeout(function(){
  $scope.$broadcast('searchQueryChanged', $location.search().q);
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

It was an easy fix. Just took a bit more digging. I was registering the $on() inside the .then() function of an initial data load which of course delayed it.